# Creating Device in C# (Device not recognized as keyword)

Tags: c#, directx, device, direct3d

I decided to try working with C# over c++ but ran into a problem.

The following code snippet shows the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using System.Device;

namespace Project_AREA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Device device;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

That's as much code as I have right now.

In `private Device device;`, the keyword `Device` is not getting recognized although all the libraries have been referenced and the `using` directives are included.

Any ideas?

Comment: inside your project.. `References` do you have the `System.Device` Dll added to the project as well..?

Comment: Yes I have System.Device DLL added in the project reference. Including the using directive using System.Device;.

Comment: what version of .Net is your project in ..? have you tried to close the VS IDE and reopen it..

Comment: Was using 4.5 changed to 4.5.1, I have closed and reopened and repaired and still not recognised as a key word :(

Comment: What `Device` class are you aiming to use? Which namespace do you expect to find it in?

Comment: DirectX and Direct3D 11

Comment: What are you developing for? Desktop, or a mobile device?

Comment: If you put a `.` after Device in the `using System.Device.` what other options do you see in the dropdown.. I wonder if there is Method Collision going on here and perhaps you will need to Alias the namespace like `using System.Device = MyDevice` then in your private do `private MyDevice device`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chwe1tc8.aspx

Comment: im developing for desktop and ill look in that djkraze just reinstalling the ide to see if that helps

Comment: @AbbyTurner DJKraze is probably correct with the name collision, although my guess is you're looking for Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb323981(v=vs.85).aspx 

Try `private Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device device;`

Comment: I looked in to the Alias and had no joy, i also tried Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device Wyatt and the Device at the end was underlined with red just the same.

Comment: Managed to Solve the problem.. for your reference and also if other run in to the same problem.

You must add all the following references to the project:
(note all files can be found on your had disk at c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\)
1: Microsoft.DirectX.dll from folder 1.0.2902.0
2: Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.dll from folder 1.0.2902.0
3: MicrosoftMicrosoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll from folder 1.0.2911.0

Thanks for the help tho guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to Solve the problem.. for your reference and also if other run in to the same problem. You must add all the following references to the project: (note all files can be found on your had disk at c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code) 1: Microsoft.DirectX.dll from folder 1.0.2902.0 2: Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.dll from folder 1.0.2902.0 3: MicrosoftMicrosoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll from folder 1.0.2911.0 Thanks for the help tho guys :)